# pyusb: scanner insufficient permissions

Tags: usb, kernel, permissions, input-device

UPDATE: I added a symbolic link to my .rules file and it is being created every time I unplug/plug the scanner. I believe my issue is more of a permissions issue with my Python code and more applicable to a different forum. Closing this as resolved for now. Updated .rules file below for reference.

```
KERNEL=="hidraw[0-3]*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1000", ATTRS{idVendor}=="e851", SYMLINK+="MyBarcoder1"
```

I'm trying to build a new rules file to help access and make use of a barcode scanner with the pyusb library. I'm not exactly sure what parameters need to be included in the rules file. I've read just about every thread I can find on the matter to no avail. Also, I'm brand new to Python and Kernels so that doesn't make this any easier. I know I need the idVendor and idProduct to identify the scanner, but I'm not really sure about the Kernel, Subsystem(s), or Group (if that's required). 
Current 63-scanner.rules

```
KERNEL=="1-1.4",SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1000", ATTRS{idVendor}=="e851"
```

Output through each hierarchical layer of the kernel.

```
pi@raspberrypi:/lib/udev/rules.d $ udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/hidraw2)
```

> Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
>   walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
>   found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
>   A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
>   and the attributes from one single parent device.
>
> looking at device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:E851:1000.0026/hidraw/hidraw2':
>       KERNEL=="hidraw2"
>       SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw"
>       DRIVER==""
>
> looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:E851:1000.0026':
>       KERNELS=="0003:E851:1000.0026"
>       SUBSYSTEMS=="hid"
>       DRIVERS=="hid-generic"
>       ATTRS{country}=="00"
>
> looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0':
>       KERNELS=="1-1.4:1.0"
>       SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
>       DRIVERS=="usbhid"
>       ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
>       ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
>       ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="03"
>       ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
>       ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="01"
>       ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="01"
>       ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="01"
>       ATTRS{interface}=="HID Interface"
>       ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"
>
> looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4':
>       KERNELS=="1-1.4"
>       SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
>       DRIVERS=="usb"
>       ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
>       ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
>       ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
>       ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
>       ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
>       ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
>       ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
>       ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="500mA"
>       ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
>       ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
>       ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0233"
>       ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
>       ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
>       ATTRS{configuration}==""
>       ATTRS{devnum}=="41"
>       ATTRS{devpath}=="1.4"
>       ATTRS{devspec}=="  (null)"
>       ATTRS{idProduct}=="1000"
>       ATTRS{idVendor}=="e851"
>       ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
>       ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Manufacturer"
>       ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
>       ATTRS{product}=="Barcode Reader"
>       ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
>       ATTRS{removable}=="removable"
>       ATTRS{speed}=="12"
>       ATTRS{urbnum}=="15"
>       ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"
>
> looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1':
>       KERNELS=="1-1"
>       SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
>       DRIVERS=="usb"
>       ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
>       ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
>       ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
>       ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
>       ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="02"
>       ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
>       ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
>       ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="2mA"
>       ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
>       ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
>       ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0200"
>       ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
>       ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
>       ATTRS{configuration}==""
>       ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
>       ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
>       ATTRS{idProduct}=="9514"
>       ATTRS{idVendor}=="0424"
>       ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
>       ATTRS{maxchild}=="5"
>       ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
>       ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
>       ATTRS{speed}=="480"
>       ATTRS{urbnum}=="1234"
>       ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
>
> looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1':
>       KERNELS=="usb1"
>       SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
>       DRIVERS=="usb"
>       ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
>       ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
>       ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
>       ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
>       ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
>       ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="01"
>       ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
>       ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
>       ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
>       ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
>       ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
>       ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0414"
>       ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
>       ATTRS{busnum}=="1"
>       ATTRS{configuration}==""
>       ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
>       ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
>       ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
>       ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
>       ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
>       ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
>       ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.14.34-v7+ dwc_otg_hcd"
>       ATTRS{maxchild}=="1"
>       ATTRS{product}=="DWC OTG Controller"
>       ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
>       ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
>       ATTRS{serial}=="3f980000.usb"
>       ATTRS{speed}=="480"
>       ATTRS{urbnum}=="26"
>       ATTRS{version}==" 2.00"
>
> looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb':
>       KERNELS=="3f980000.usb"
>       SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
>       DRIVERS=="dwc_otg"
>       ATTRS{busconnected}=="Bus Connected = 0x1"
>       ATTRS{buspower}=="Bus Power = 0x1"
>       ATTRS{bussuspend}=="Bus Suspend = 0x0"
>       ATTRS{devspeed}=="Device Speed = 0x0"
>       ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
>       ATTRS{enumspeed}=="Device Enumeration Speed = 0x1"
>       ATTRS{fr_interval}=="Frame Interval = 0x1d4b"
>       ATTRS{ggpio}=="GGPIO = 0x00000000"
>       ATTRS{gnptxfsiz}=="GNPTXFSIZ = 0x01000306"
>       ATTRS{gotgctl}=="GOTGCTL = 0x001c0001"
>       ATTRS{gpvndctl}=="GPVNDCTL = 0x00000000"
>       ATTRS{grxfsiz}=="GRXFSIZ = 0x00000306"
>       ATTRS{gsnpsid}=="GSNPSID = 0x4f54280a"
>       ATTRS{guid}=="GUID = 0x2708a000"
>       ATTRS{gusbcfg}=="GUSBCFG = 0x20001700"
>       ATTRS{hcd_frrem}=="HCD Dump Frame Remaining"
>       ATTRS{hcddump}=="HCD Dump"
>       ATTRS{hnp}=="HstNegScs = 0x0"
>       ATTRS{hnpcapable}=="HNPCapable = 0x1"
>       ATTRS{hprt0}=="HPRT0 = 0x00001005"
>       ATTRS{hptxfsiz}=="HPTXFSIZ = 0x02000406"
>       ATTRS{hsic_connect}=="HSIC Connect = 0x1"
>       ATTRS{inv_sel_hsic}=="Invert Select HSIC = 0x0"
>       ATTRS{mode}=="Mode = 0x1"
>       ATTRS{mode_ch_tim_en}=="Mode Change Ready Timer Enable = 0x0"
>       ATTRS{rd_reg_test}=="Time to read GNPTXFSIZ reg 10000000 times: 1230 msecs (123 jiffies)"
>       ATTRS{regdump}=="Register Dump"
>       ATTRS{regoffset}=="0xffffffff"
>       ATTRS{regvalue}=="invalid offset"
>       ATTRS{rem_wakeup_pwrdn}==""
>       ATTRS{remote_wakeup}=="Remote Wakeup Sig = 0 Enabled = 0 LPM Remote Wakeup = 0"
>       ATTRS{spramdump}=="SPRAM Dump"
>       ATTRS{srp}=="SesReqScs = 0x1"
>       ATTRS{srpcapable}=="SRPCapable = 0x1"
>       ATTRS{wr_reg_test}=="Time to write GNPTXFSIZ reg 10000000 times: 410 msecs (41 jiffies)"
>
> looking at parent device '/devices/platform/soc':
>       KERNELS=="soc"
>       SUBSYSTEMS=="platform"
>       DRIVERS==""
>       ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
>
> looking at parent device '/devices/platform':
>       KERNELS=="platform"
>       SUBSYSTEMS==""
>       DRIVERS==""

Tailing the syslog to see what happens when the scanner is unplugged/plugged.

- Jun 20 15:32:59 raspberrypi kernel: [102427.935608] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 41
- Jun 20 15:33:05 raspberrypi kernel: [102434.154884] usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 42 using dwc_otg
- Jun 20 15:33:05 raspberrypi kernel: [102434.288366] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=e851, idProduct=1000
- Jun 20 15:33:05 raspberrypi kernel: [102434.288377] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
- Jun 20 15:33:05 raspberrypi kernel: [102434.288381] usb 1-1.4: Product: Barcode Reader
- Jun 20 15:33:05 raspberrypi kernel: [102434.288386] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Manufacturer
- Jun 20 15:33:05 raspberrypi kernel: [102434.294652] input: Manufacturer Barcode Reader as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:E851:1000.0027/input/input38
- Jun 20 15:33:05 raspberrypi kernel: [102434.355736] hid-generic 0003:E851:1000.0027: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.01 Keyboard [Manufacturer Barcode Reader] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.4/input0
- Jun 20 15:33:05 raspberrypi mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 42: "/sys/devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4"
- Jun 20 15:33:05 raspberrypi mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 42 was not an MTP device
- Jun 20 15:33:05 raspberrypi systemd-udevd[11633]: Process '/usr/sbin/th-cmd --socket /var/run/thd.socket --passfd --udev' failed with exit code 1.

Comment: Your rule doesn't appear to do anything, it lists conditions but no action. Is that intended?

Comment: I don't need it to launch a script of any sort, if that's what you're asking. All I need it to do is allow me to access a barcode scanner, the same way, every time it's plugged in. In order to make use of pyusb (libusb) library, I need to be able to access the scanner and pull configurations. I believe that I should be able to do that if I create the rule file the correct way. Which obviously, I haven't done.

Comment: I'm glad you have resolved this. In retrospective, do you think it was possible for someone to deduce from your question that you needed `SYMLINK+="MyBarcoder1"` as action?

Comment: No, probably not.